# Determine if a function is async-signal-safe (can be called inside a signal handler)

Tags: objective-c, c, posix, signals

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to conclusively determine if a function is async-signal-safe if you don't have access to its implementation?
2. If not, is there a way to test if function would be async-signal-safe enough to call from a signal handler?

If you reads the man pages of signal() or sigaction(), you get a list of async-signal-safe functions (functions that can be safely called inside a signal handler). However, I believe that this list is not exhaustive. For example, the following page http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal, under the **Async-signal-safe functions** header, reads:

> POSIX.1-2004 (also known as POSIX.1-2001 Technical Corrigendum 2) requires an implementation to guarantee that the following functions can be safely called inside a signal handler:

And then it proceeds to list the normal async-signal-safe functions listed in the man pages above. As I read it, it says "it requires", not "these are the only ones".

For example, [this site](http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/3c/backtrace_symbols_fd/) says that back_trace_symbols_fd() is async-signal safe. That function obtains is data from dladdr() and it doesn't use malloc() like back_trace_symbols(), so it looks like it may be safe. Also, I did some testing, and the output struct of dladdr() contains char* variables, but these are NOT malloc'ed at runtime. The char string they point to exists at run-time even before dladdr() is called.

Any thoughts or ideas that can point me in the right direction are appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget to up vote useful answers to your questions, or to accept the most useful answer to each of your questions.  If you're not sure, look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and especially [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have access to the function's implementation, you can look at the manual page.  If the manual page doesn't say it is async-safe, and the POSIX standard doesn't say it is async-safe, the only safe conclusion is "it is not async-safe" (coupled with "do not use it").

There is no 100% reliable way to test whether a function is async-safe.  Remember, testing can only show the presence of bugs, not their absence (Dijkstra).  The mere fact that you don't manage to tickle the function into misbehaving under test may simply mean that your testing is not adequate (but rest assured, the important customer who you can't afford to offend will immediately and accidentally devise a devastatingly effective test that demonstrates that the function is not async-safe almost as soon as you release the code with the faulty assumption).

Comment: This approach is rather frustrating, since for example `strlen` and `memcpy` are not guaranteed async-signal safe. But you just have to live with it - you never know when some bright spark is going to invent a fabulously optimized `memcpy` that genuinely isn't re-entrant. Anyway the C standard says that library functions in general cannot be called from signal handlers at all (async-signal-unsafe merely says that it cannot be called from a handler for a signal that just so happened to interrupt another unsafe function, but that's a tricky thing to actually get any advantage out of).

Comment: @SteveJessop strlen() is not defined as async-signal-safe in the man page of sigaction(), but you can implement your own version of it that is async-signal-safe. All it does is it counts the non-NULL characters and when you reach NULL return that value.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do you know why some man pages specify thread-safety and signal-safety while others don't? I'm guessing I should follow the man pages of my own OS. Some man pages specify an attributes(5) function (not sure if it is a function) that specifies all of this and more. Do you know how to access that? See Example man page: http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?dladdr+3

Comment: To get at `attributes(5)`, use `man 5 attributes` or `man -s 5 attributes`.  Some manual pages are written more carefully than others.

Answer (score 0):

What are you hoping to achieve in the signal handler?  You should consider whether it is the right place for it.  It is probably best to follow the advice of the man page:

```
In general, signal handlers should do little more  
than set a flag; most other actions are not safe.
```

Comment: You can do way more inside a signal handler. You just have to be careful. Look at this for example: http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/