# Is there an async-safe way to get the current thread ID in Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, pthreads, signals, posix

Is there any way to get the current thread ID from a signal handler in Linux? The `getpid()` method does what I want, but it is not clear if it is async-safe. `man 7 signal` provides a list of POSIX methods which are async safe, but this tells us nothing about non-POSIX methods such as `getpid()`. Presumably some of the many non-POSIX methods Linux has added are async safe, but I can't find the list.

There is also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9014993/149138) which claims that all direct (not multiplexed) syscalls are async safe, but provides no evidence.

The goal is to build some kind of async-safe thread local storage, since `__thread` [is not safe](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2012-06/msg00335.html) in the general case.

It doesn't have to be the "Linux thread ID" - any consistent thread ID would be fine. For example `pthread_self` would be great, but there is nothing claiming that is async safe. If we examine the implementation of that method in glibc Linux, it defers to the THREAD_SELF macro, which looks like:

```
# define THREAD_SELF \
({ struct pthread *__self;                                                  \
  asm ("movl %%gs:%c1,%0" : "=r" (__self)                                  \
          : "i" (offsetof (struct pthread, header.self)));                    \
  __self;})
```

It *seems* to be that this should be async-safe, if the thread in question was created under a regime that populates the `gs` resgister (perhaps all threads in Linux are, I'm not sure). Still looking at [that header](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/sysdeps/i386/tls.h) makes me pretty scared...

Comment: Wouldn't you use `pthread_self` for a thread ID?

Comment: That would be fine also, but there is no indication that method is async-safe, and it is not true that pthreads methods are async safe in general (certainly, the mutex methods are not).

Maybe I could use the platform specific implementation of `pthread_self` to hack up an explicit version of the method that I know to be threadsafe?

Comment: That inline asm snippet is certainly async-safe. What evil could happen if another signal is received while this executes? None. (Note by the way that `getpid` is not really much of a syscall -- glibc only does a "syscall" on the first attempt and caches the value thereafter, and the "syscall" in reality goes into the vDSO).

Comment: Right, I think the inline asm is safe too, but it just happens to be a particular implementation on some platform, and doens't a guarantee that the implementation won't change in the future etc. In fact, I realize now I grabbed the 32-bit implementation - I believe it's different in x64 (more relevant to my case).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Async-signal-safe access to __thread variables from dlopen()ed libraries?](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2012-06/msg00335.html) you provided (emphasis is mine):

> The __thread variables generally fit the bill (at least on Linux/x86),
>   when the variable is in the main executable, or in a directly-linked DSO.
>
> But when the DSO is dlopen()ed (and does not use initial-exec TLS model),
>   **the first access to TLS variable from a given thread triggers a call to
>   malloc**...

In other words, it only requires one access to that thread specific variable to bring it to life and make it available in signal handlers. E.g.:

1. Block the signals you are interested in in the parent thread before creating a child thread.
2. Unblock those interesting signals in the parent thread after the call to `pthread_create`.
3. In the child thread initialize your `__thread` variable and unblock those interesting signals.

I normally store the write end of a unix pipe in that tread-specific variable and the signal handler writes the signal number into that pipe. The read end of the pipe is registered with `select/epoll` in that same thread, so that I can handle signals outside of the signal context. E.g.:

```
__thread int signal_pipe; // initialized at thread start

extern "C" void signal_handler(int signo, siginfo_t*, void*)
{
    unsigned char signo_byte = static_cast<unsigned>(signo); // truncate
    ::write(signal_pipe, &signo_byte, 1); // standard unix self pipe trick
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution isn't possible in my scenario (a library) because I don't have any hooks into thread creation so I can't perform the hand off you describe.

Comment: @BeeOnRope I see. [You can always hook into library calls though](http://www.opensourceforu.com/2011/08/lets-hook-a-library-function/). You could hook into `pthread_create`...